# getting require is not a function error in angular though being declared in the app.module

Tags: angular

I am trying to render a bellcurve chart and getting the error require is not a function in angular. I have declared require in the app.module .

If you notice i am trying to load the chart via the hellocomponent.

I have created a stackblitz for it. Could somebody tell me what the problem is
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgx6up

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed with the following,

```
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';

export function highchartsFactory() {
  return highcharts;
}
```

and here is the related **[`Issue`](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/178#issuecomment-304833680)**.

Here is the working **[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renb81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**. However there is a small modification you need to do on the configuration, i assume you should be able to handle that.

Comment: There is still error in the stackblitz code. The chart isnt loading

Comment: Thats what i mentoned in the answer, if you look at the error and click it it will take you to the highcharts site. you need to change the data for the chart

Comment: @Sajeetharan This is working because we removed use of `require` entirely from the `highchartsFactory` function. What was the problem with the original code? Why doesn't `require` work?

Comment: @yeshashah that's the recommendation given to import highcharts. Still you can use require as mentioned in the GitHub issue

Comment: @Tom Did the answer help you

Comment: No sorry it didn't help

Comment: I just changed using a different angular wrapper

Comment: oh dear! even if you change the wrapper you will end up in the same error! just fix your configuraiton, everything will be sorted

Answer (score -3):

Tom, you can find working code with example at https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could let me know what is wrong with my piece of code.